# Can't extract the text and find all by BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I want to extract the all the available items in the équipements, but I can only get the first four items, and then I got '+ plus'.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6'}
url = 'https://www.airbnb.fr/rooms/8261637?s=bAMrFL5A'
req = urllib2.Request(url = url, headers = headers)
html = urllib2.urlopen(req)
bsobj = BeautifulSoup(html.read(),'lxml')
b = bsobj.findAll("div",{"class": "row amenities"})
```

for the result of b, it does not return all the list inside the tag.
And for the last one of it is '+ plus', looks like as following.

```
<span data-reactid=".mjeft4n4sg.0.0.0.0.1.8.1.0.0.$1.1.0.0">+ Plus</span></strong></a></div></div></div></div></div>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because data filled up using reactjs after page load. So if you download it via requests you can't see the data.

Instead you have to use [selenium web driver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), open page and process all the javascripts. Then you can get ccess to all data you expect

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved the problem by using selenium and phantomjs