# Scraping elements rendered using React JS with BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, reactjs, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape anchor links with class="_1UoZlX" from the search results from this particular page - https://www.flipkart.com/search?as=on&as-pos=1_1_ic_sam&as-show=on&otracker=start&page=6&q=samsung+mobiles&sid=tyy%2F4io

When I created a soup from the page I realised that the search results are being rendered using React JS and hence I can't find them in the page source (or in the soup).

Here's my code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


listUrls = ['https://www.flipkart.com/search?as=on&as-pos=1_1_ic_sam&as-show=on&otracker=start&page=6&q=samsung+mobiles&sid=tyy%2F4iof']
PHANTOMJS_PATH = './phantomjs'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(PHANTOMJS_PATH)
urls=[]

for url in listUrls:
    browser.get(url)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "_1UoZlX")))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,"html.parser")
    results = soup.findAll('a',{'class':"_1UoZlX"})
    for result in results:
        link = result["href"]
        print link
        urls.append(link)
    print urls
```

This is the error I'm getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fetch_urls.py", line 19, in <module>
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "_1UoZlX")))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: 
Screenshot: available via screen
```

Someone mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34363121/cant-extract-the-text-and-find-all-by-beautifulsoup) that there is a way to use selenium to process the javascript on a page. Can someone elaborate on that? I did some googling but couldn't find an approach that works for this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no problem with your code but the website you are scraping - it does not stop loading for some reason that prevents the parsing of the page and subsequent code you wrote.

I tried with wikipedia to confirm the same:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

listUrls = ["https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_state_and_union_territory_capitals_in_India"]
# browser = webdriver.PhantomJS('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')
browser = webdriver.Chrome("./chromedriver")
urls=[]

for url in listUrls:
    browser.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,"html.parser")
    results = soup.findAll('a',{'class':"mw-redirect"})
    for result in results:
        link = result["href"]
        urls.append(link)
    print urls
```

**Outputs:**

```
[u'/wiki/List_of_states_and_territories_of_India_by_area', u'/wiki/List_of_Indian_states_by_GDP_per_capita', u'/wiki/Constitutional_republic', u'/wiki/States_and_territories_of_India', u'/wiki/National_Capital_Territory_of_Delhi', u'/wiki/States_Reorganisation_Act', u'/wiki/High_Courts_of_India', u'/wiki/Delhi_NCT', u'/wiki/Bengaluru', u'/wiki/Madras', u'/wiki/Andhra_Pradesh_Capital_City', u'/wiki/States_and_territories_of_India', u'/wiki/Jammu_(city)']
```

P.S. I'm using a chrome driver in order to run the script against the real chrome browser for debugging purposes. Download the chrome driver from https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.27/

Answer (score 0):

Selenium will render the page including the Javascript. Your code is working properly. It is waiting for the element to be generated. In your case, Selenium didn't get that CSS element. The URL which you gave is not rendering the result page. Instead of that, It is generating the following error page.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C6BW.jpg

This page is not having the CSS class. Your code is waiting for that particular CSS element. Try `Firefox` web driver to see what is happening.

Comment: I'm using a headless browser. May be that's why. Will try with a regular browser.

Comment: Headless browser should work fine. Regular browser will be easy to see the output. You can switch to regular browser once the problem is fixed.

Flipkart is opening the error page most of the time. You should make the script to click Retry button whenever it happens.