# Python beautiful soup doesn't locate a span element

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm testing instagram on the following Instagram page: https://www.instagram.com/acmilan/ and trying to get the posts element (right now = '4,552 posts').
If I inspect the page, the HTML looks like the attached screenshot.
My code to locate that element is:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
elements = soup.find_all("ul", text=re.compile("posts"))
print(len(elements))
```

but this doesn't find anything.
Then, I tried:

```
elements = soup.find_all("span", text=re.compile("posts"))
print(len(elements))
```

and still nothing.
Then, I tried:

```
elements = soup.find_all(True, text=re.compile('posts'))
```

and again, nothing.[image]

it seems quite an easy task, but somehow I can't find a solution. Any suggestions?
Thank you

Comment: that data is rendered via JavaScript and thus is not accessible via BeautifulSoup because BS can only access static HTML. You'll probably need to use Selenium to render the ReactJS contents, then can parse those contents with BeautifulSoup similar to this Q&A: [Scraping elements rendered using React JS with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331423/scraping-elements-rendered-using-react-js-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: I'm trying to edit my question but I can't find a way to do it. I forgot to mention that "soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')" and driver is coming from selenium.

Comment: In that case, your code works when I run it. Try using: `elements = soup.find('span', {'class': "g47SY "});

print(elements.text)`

Comment: @davedwards thank you Dave. The thing is, I would need to find the element using the text "post" rather than the class value, since that often changes. Can you think about a solution that would be based on the keyword 'post'? Thanks

Comment: yes sure I could provide a solution, but first have you checked any of the answers below?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I got around it with this code.Make sure that you install the `re` module.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/acmilan/'
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
find = soup.findAll('meta')
meta = re.findall('g,.+\ Posts', str(find))[0]
print(meta.replace('g, ', '').replace('Posts', ''))

Output: 4,552
```

Comment: thank you very much. May I ask why you use 'meta' and not tag information like 'span' and 'li'? The element is visible on the screen, so shouldn't I be able to locate it if I use as source selenium page_source?

Comment: javascript brochacho

Comment: @Angelo does the code work for you? You won't be able to get the data that you want because there are scripts running on the site, especially instagram. The info you were looking for just so happened to be in the <meta> tag. I used `re` to pull the data with regex and got the info out.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. Even though your solution does help, in my specific case I had to go down another path. The number of posts is not inside a javascript and is displayed in the browswer through a li and span element. So I decided to build a list of all the div, span, and li elements, check their text value until I locate the number of posts. I need this less efficient solution because today the posts number is located inside the meta element but tomorrow it may not. The only "constant" in all this will literally be the word 'posts'. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

to get posts count you don't need `BeautifulSoup` or `selenium`, use `regex` or even better using `json`

```
import requests
import re
import json

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/acmilan/'
page = requests.get(url)
postCount = re.search('timeline_media":{"count":(\d+)', page.text)
print('regex: ' + postCount.groups()[0])

# using json
jString = re.search('window._sharedData = (\{.+?\});</script>', page.text)
json_data = json.loads(jString.groups()[0])
postCount = json_data['entry_data']['ProfilePage'][0]['graphql']['user']['edge_owner_to_timeline_media']['count']
print('json: ' + str(postCount))

# to show all json object
# print(json_data)
```

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. even though it does the job, there's no guarantee the 'posts' number will always be inside timeline_media. Unfortunately I need a more long-term solution that could face situation in which the posts element is moved to other part of the code. If you can think about a way to purely use the word 'posts' and nothing else to locate the number that would be exactly what I need. Thanks!

Comment: regex maybe easy to change/break, but not json it is in same format since 2013 or even earlier