# How do I webscrape my localhost react app?

Tags: reactjs, web-scraping

I'm trying to figure out how to web-scrape my website if it uses react; previous attempts at webscraping using cheerio have failed, since whenever I call $('theTagIWantToFind') it returns null. I printed the html and only found what was on my index.html file, instead of what I would find if I did inspect element.

```
request('http://192.168.43.210:5000/', (error, response, html) => {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    console.log($('h1'));
  }
});
```

Comment: This looks good: https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/

Comment: Try selenium. Here's an example from a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331423/scraping-elements-rendered-using-react-js-with-beautifulsoup