# Trying to scrapy the link from website, in view page source cannot see it, but if I inspect one special item on page, it shows the href link

Tags: python, scrapy

The page I am playing on is this https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://cd.lianjia.com/, I want to get into the pages this webarchive saved at different time point as showed with dots in calendar, but in the view page source I cannot find any href link for the different timepoint. If I click inspect on the one timepoint I can see the href link is there.
Here is my code:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.request
url = 'https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://cd.lianjia.com/'
page = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the `calendar grid` class you'll find a hierarchy of tags that eventually lead to each day of each week of each month. The days with associated archives will have have an `calendar-day` div and associated `href`.

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply, especially my question looks so ugly. yes, when I inspect the special day, I can see the href link, but when I use the BeautifulSoup open it , all the href relate to the calendar time point is not inside, I want to use the scrapy get all this link out, what should I do next?

Comment: The `react-wayback-search` element isn't loading in time for beautiful soup. This post ([linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41331423/scraping-elements-rendered-using-react-js-with-beautifulsoup)) might be helpful to you.